# Excel Function / Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'll try to explain this the best i can:

I've got 4 cells that or display "" or display "Inválido" depending on the content of **other cells** **( this are not the 1.,2.,3.,4. cells that im refering)**

**1.Cell -** This cell will show "" if all the other cells  are filled and within the right conditions" otherwise it shows "Inválido"

**2. Cell-** This cell will do the same as de above cell (1.) but **ONLY** will show "Inválido" if any of the cells that fit in the conditions are filled with anything , so if all the fields on the cells are empty , it just displays ""

So i want to display "" if it fits in the conditions and display "" too if all the fields are empty. I've been trying this for a long time and i can't figure it out.

**3.Cell**- --

**4.Cell** --

Both goes for the other cells

I think my problem is an  encapsulation problem

```
=IF(AND(B32>0;H32>0;N32>0;B35>0;D35>0;F35>0;H35>0;F35>=H24;N32>=N21;D35>B35;OR( AND(B32="";H32="";N32="";B35="";D35="";F35="";H35="";) )); "";"Inválido")
```

Comment: can you post an image?

Comment: thanks for trying to help but i already made it, i'll post the answers as it might help someone with encapsulation syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Answer: `=IF(OR(E(B32>0;H32>0;N32>0;B35>0;D35>0;F35>0;H35>0;F35>=H24;F35<H35;D35>B35;N32>=N21);AND(B32="";H32="";N32="";H35="";F35="";D35="";B35=""));"";"Inválido")`